# Perl Packer not operating as expected

Tags: perl, module, strawberry-perl, pp-perl-par-packager

I've recently installed the Perl Packer module to compile my perl scripts into exe packages. I'm running strawberry perl setup on a windows 32-bit machine. When I attempt to run the pp -o command, I get an error stating that Perl is not part of my path. It is, for some reason, looking for perl in F:/Programs/Strawberry Perl/site/bin/perl.exe, when the true path is F:/Programs/Strawberry Perl/bin/perl.exe. Perl itself runs fine from commandline. How can I get Perl Packer to find my perl.exe?

Answer (score 0):

What about calling this way?

```
perl pp {your options goes here}
```

regards

Comment: Can't open perl script "pp": No such file or directory.